# Getting TimeoutError from async.io for Discord Bot

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

Here is my code

```py
 bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I did make a `.env` file and put my Token there ( I checked again for my token from discord developers page and pasted the current one so there's no way i am giving the wrong token )
and then when i do `python3 bot.py` ( i saved it as bot.py) The thing literally stands there until `async.io` gives a timeout error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 17, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 165, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 582, in _request
    break
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 596, in __exit__
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
```

I was following this [webpage](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/)

and Later I decided to go to the "Official Documentation" and there i followed a [Quickstart Guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)
which also resulted in the same error

Comment: If the code from the Quickstart Guide does not work for you it's either your installed `discord` version (check with `python -m pip freeze`) or a connection problem of your machine. I'm assuming that the token you provided is correct.

Comment: `discord.py==1.3.3`
says the code that you gave. Also the fact that I am surfing the web and watching videos should mean that theres no connection problem right ?

Comment: A aiohttp TimeoutError tells me that you are making a request but it's not answering you which is a connection problem. Why the connection problem exists I cannot tell you. The Quickstart Guide example is working on my side.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out  I am going to Try if i can change the hotspot  I was using .

Comment: Actually I still dont know about the network but the token is being continuously changed by discord every time i log in and out of the private page in firefox

Comment: Yes I did Log in ! Finally , i dont know why discord keeps changing it .